# How to configure ActiveMQ Artemis server for remote access?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have ActiveMQ Artemis server installed on a Unix box. I am able to create an Artemis broker instance which provides me with link to web console which is running on `localhost`.

Now I want access web console from an external machine, probably running Windows.

Can you please guide me on step by step process to configure the ActiveMQ Artemis server so that I can access it from another machine?

Comment: did you try and replace localhost with the servers external or real IP? presuming this is jetty your using. This is also off-topic here as it's not a programming question and your looking for an external reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded Jetty web server which is used to host the web console is configured in the `bootstrap.xml` file in the `etc` directory of your Artemis instance. Look for the `web` element in that file. You'll need to change its `bind` attribute to use something other than `localhost` since `localhost` is only accessible from the machine where the server is running. Typically this will be the externally accessible host name or IP address of the server.

You can find more information about configuring the embedded Jetty web server in the [Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/web-server.html).